# Access database form showing a pop up instead of inserting data

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I have this code behind a button on my form

```
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim name As String
 nameAdd.SetFocus
 name = nameAdd.Text

   strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer (CustomerName) VALUES (" & name & ");"
   DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

but when i run it, this pops up.

[PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb92t.png)

I have no idea why this pops up, if i fill the dialog box in, it will then insert a new row to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the single quotes into the SQL, meaning your command becomes:

```
INSERT INTO tblCustomer (CustomerName) VALUES (testnameexample);
```

Add quotes to the value...

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblCustomer (CustomerName) VALUES ('" & name & "');"
```

Which makes the command:

```
INSERT INTO tblCustomer (CustomerName) VALUES ('testnameexample');
```

Comment: i didn't even notice that, works great now thank you.